# Issue of while Authenticate with Azure Container Registry from Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-container-registry, azure-aks

I created the Azure Kubernetes Service and Azure Container Registry using Azure Portal. After that I am able to give the Grant AKS access to ACR, for that I used the below script:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionID 'XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX'
#Get the id of the service principal configured for AKS
$AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP = "DSEU2-AKSRES-SB-DEV-RGP-01"
$AKS_CLUSTER_NAME = "DSEU2-AKSRES-SB-DEV-AKS-01"
$CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name     $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)

# Get the ACR registry resource id
$ACR_NAME = "DSWEAKSRESSBDEVACR01"
$ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP = "DSWE-AKSRES-SB-DEV-RGP-01"
$ACR_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --resource-group $ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP --query "id" --output tsv)

#Create role assignment
az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role Reader --scope $ACR_ID
```

Whenever I am running the above PowerShell script then I am getting the exception like shown in below figure.
[image]

For the above scenario I followed this documentation:[Authenticate with Azure Container Registry from Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2fazure%2faks%2ftoc.json#grant-aks-access-to-acr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the command [`az role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create), the description for the argument with `--assignee`:

> Represent a user, group, or service principal. supported format:
>   object id, user sign-in name, or service principal name.

But what you use is the resource Id of Azure Kubernetes cluster. So you get the error.

And the link you posted, the document shows the secret in the yaml file and the secret created with the command `kubectl create secret`. The secret just be used for pulling the image from the Azure Container Registry.

**Update**

With the ERROR shows, the resource group could not be found, so you should check your resource group carefully.

And from your script, you use PowerShell command to log in and use CLI to execute. I think the subscription will not be changed for CLI. So you can check if you are in the correct subscription. PowerShell command will not change the Subscription for CLI.
[image]

So I suggest the CLI command [`az account set --subscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-set).

Comment: Thanks @Charles, I am getting the error at this line `$CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)`. and also see the updated link I was mentioned in the above question.

Comment: Verify and check the resource group your cluster was deployed to and that it's in the right subscription : You specified "DSEU2-AKSRES-SB-DEV-RGP-01". The error explicitly says it cannot find the resource group - so perhaps a typo in the name or the wrong subscription is selected.

Comment: The same script will work in another machine. I used the az login and set the current subscription. and resource group is also exists in my azure subscription.

Comment: @pradeep I update the answer. And if you want to change the subscription, you cloud use the command `Select-AzureRmSubscription`. But for your script, I suggest you can use CLI command to change the subscription.

Comment: @pradeep Powershell command will not change the subscription for CLI.

Comment: You can ask another question and give more details so that you can get the right answer more quickly.